# Modelling Forced Oscillations with a Single Trigonometric Function

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

In [a physics book](https://openstax.org/books/university-physics-volume-1/pages/15-6-forced-oscillations) I came across the following solution to a differential equation modeling forced, damped, oscillating motion: $$x(t)=A\cos(\omega t+\phi)$$ where $$A=\frac{F_0}{\sqrt{m^2\left(\omega^2-\omega_0^2\right)^2+b^2\omega^2}}$$ The differential equation which prompted this solution is $$-kx-b\dot{x}+F_0\sin(\omega t)=m\ddot{x}$$

This doesn't feel quite intuitively right, however. When the angular frequency $\omega$ of the thing which is causing the forced oscillating is equal to the natural angular frequency $\omega_0$ of the system it is causing an oscillation in, this seems to work intuitively. But when this isn't the case, it seems like $x(t)$ cannot be modeled as a single trig function, but rather a combination of multiple.

For example, in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jewSVEBkI_s&ab_channel=AnimatedScience) at 1:26, the frequency $\omega$ of the vibration generator is set to 2Hz, which is different than the natural frequency $\omega_0$ of the system (this turns out to be $\approx3.33$Hz) and the motion of the mass does not appear to resemble a single trig function, but rather multiple.

Here is my best attempt to graph the seeming motion at 1:26:[image]

$$f(x)=\cos(x)-\cos(2x)$$

My question: **Is the formula incorrect/a simplified version? If so, what is the correct one? If not, where am I going wrong here?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution of a forced and damped harmonic oscillator
$$m\ddot{x}=-kx - b\dot{x} +F_0 \cos\omega_{\text{d}} t$$
is actually the sum of steady-state part $x_{\text{s}}$ and a transient part $x_{\text{t}}$
$$x = x_{\text{s}} + x_{\text{t}}$$
where
$$x_{\text{s}} \sim A\cos(\omega t+\phi) \\ x_{\text{t}} \sim A' e^{-\gamma t} \sin (\omega' t+\phi')$$

The transient part depends on the initial conditions and both parts are present at the start. As time goes on, the transient part decays exponentially, leaving only the steady-state solution, which is the one you quoted. The full equations can be found [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscdr.html#c2). Therefore, at the beginning, the motion will not be a single pure trig function but rather a sum of two trig functions.

Answer (score 2):

When watching the [video (beginning at around 0:35)](https://youtu.be/jewSVEBkI_s?t=36) carefully,
we can see that the driving element (at the bottom of the device)
does not move in a purely sine oscillation.
It moves more like this:

[image]

The driving movement is still a periodic, but not a sine-like function.

You can decompose this oscillation (like every periodic motion)
into a [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series) of several pure sine oscillations.

In this case the Fourier decomposition is roughly like this:
$$F(t)= F_0( \sin(\omega t) + 0.33\sin(3\omega t) + 0.2\sin(5\omega t) + ...)$$

You see, the movement contains not only the base frequency $\omega$,
but also higher frequencies (which are multiples of the base frequency).

To  convince you of the validity of the Fourier decomposition,
here is a plot of $F(t)$ with only the first 3 components of the
series being considered. When considering even more higher frequency
components, then  the series would approximate the function from the
first image even better.

[image]
<sub>(image created by [FooPlot](http://www.fooplot.com))</sub>

Then the solution of the differential equation
$$-kx-b\dot{x}+F(t)=m\ddot{x}$$

will be
$$\begin{align}
x(t) &= A(\omega)\cos(\omega t+\phi(\omega)) \\
 &+ 0.33 A(3\omega)\cos(3\omega t+\phi(3\omega)) \\
 &+ 0.2 A(5\omega)\cos(5\omega t+\phi(5\omega)) \\
 &+ ...
\end{align}$$

where $A(\omega)$ is still the expression as given in your question
and $\phi(\omega)$ is another expression which can also be calculated
from the differential equation.
It is no surprise, that the response $x(t)$ contains not only the base
frequency $\omega$, but also the higher frequencies.
Especially, when one of these higher frequencies ($n\omega$) happens
to be near to the resonance frequency ($\omega_0$), then the
component with $A(n\omega)$ will be quite large.
This is exactly what you could observe in the video.